# tkinter scroll bar inactive

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am trying to get a vertical scrollbar working with tkinter.  I am using the code below.  The scroll bar shows up until I uncomment the line

```
#canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
```

What am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root =tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, height=200, width=200, background="blue")

yscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)

frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ewns')

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

root.mainloop()
```

[scrollbar inactive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sybi6.png)

Comment: It is inactive because the scrollregion is not set or smaller than the canvas size.

Comment: hi, I have updated the code trying to set the scroll region .... but still no love

Comment: There is nothing in the canvas, so `canvas.bbox('all')` returns `None`, add some items which make the scrollregion larger than the canvas size and see the result.

Comment: that did that trick.  Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, the scrollregion was smaller than the canvas size...

got it working

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root =tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, height=100, width=100)
frame.pack()

frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, height=200, width=200, background="blue")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ewns')

yscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

frame_buttons = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="green")
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame_buttons, anchor="nw")

rows = 9
columns = 5

buttons = [[tk.Button() for j in range(columns)] for i in range(rows)]
for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, columns):
        buttons[i][j] = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text=("%d,%d" % (i+1, j+1)))
        buttons[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='news')
    
frame_buttons.update_idletasks()



canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

root.mainloop()
```

[image]