# The tkinter scrollbar doesn't work and remains active throughout

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I've already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444467/tkinter-scroll-bar-inactive) question out but it doesn't answer my question

I have the following code:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
Scr = Scrollbar(root)
Scr.pack(side = RIGHT,fill =Y)
cnvs = Canvas(root,width = 800,height = 560,yscrollcommand = Scr.set)
cnvs.place(x=0,y=40)
for i in range(100):
    x = Label(cnvs,text=f"This is label {i}")
    x.pack()
Scr.config(command = cnvs.yview)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this, the scrollbar doesn't work and remains inactive throughout.
[image: Here's what I'm talking about]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things:

When you want to scroll widgets placed on a canvas you should use canvas methods such as `create_text()`and not `pack()` or `grid()` them, otherwise they will not scroll.

Then you have to provide the canvas a scrolling region. Put objects on canvas FIRST, then define scrollregion.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200+800+50')

mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.pack(pady=10, padx=10, expand='yes', fill='both')
# Making sure only canvas will change with window size
mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

scr = Scrollbar(mainframe, orient='vertical')
scr.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns')

canvas = Canvas(mainframe, bg='khaki', yscrollcommand=scr.set)
canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='ewns')
scr.config(command=canvas.yview)

for i in range(100):
    # Create canvas objects at canvas positions
    canvas.create_text(0, 20*i, text=f"This is label {i}", anchor='w')
    # Create objects and pack them, will NOT scroll
    x = Label(canvas,text=f"Will not scroll {i}")
    x.pack()

# Define scrollregion AFTER widgets are placed on canvas
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation! Just wanted to ask if it's always necessary to create a `Frame`?

Comment: No, but I usually do that so I can handle the scrolled canvas as one unit.